# Error converting data type varchar to numeric - but with numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table in SQL Server 2014:

```
effDate  DATETIME(23) NOT NULL  
rateType CHAR(2) NOT NULL  
rate     DECIMAL(10, 8) NOT NULL
```

When I run the following query, I get an error message:

> Select Failed: 8114 Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

My query:

```
insert into hprs.dbo.OHPRSrates 
values ('01/01/2019', 'D', 0.02642000)
```

Why? The only numeric column in this row is `rate` and the insert value is clearly numeric

Comment: Any triggers?..

Comment: What is that `DATETIME(23)` datatype?? Is it just a silly typo and you really mean `DATETIME2(3)` ?? Also: when using dates in string literal form, I'd always recommend to use the **ISO-8601** format `YYYYMMDD` (no dashes or anything) to be independent of any language & regional settings in your SQL Server

Answer (score 5):

I *suspect* those columns are not in the order you believe they are in. When inserting, you should really declare the columns you're inserting into. Does this, by any chance, work?

```
INSERT INTO hprs.dbo.OHPRSrates (effDate,rateType,rate)
VALUES ('01/01/2019','D',0.02642000);
```

Also, however, I would recommend using a unambiguous date format, such as `yyyyMMdd`. Thus, for your date, `'20190101'`. A value of `01/01/2019` is 01 January what ever way you read it, however, is `01/02/2019` 02 January or 01 February? The answer depends on your language (settings).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
insert into hprs.dbo.OHPRSrates 
(effDate, rateType, rate) values ('01/01/2019','D',0.02642000)
```

Comment: That was a good idea adding the column names, but "insert into hprs.dbo.OHPRSrates (effdate,ratetype,rate) values ('01/01/2019','D',0.02642000)" does not work. Same error. I also tried converting the date value to datetime, just in case that was the problem, but that didn't help. Any other ideas? This query has actually been running for years, so I don't know what's different.

Comment: Considering this is the same SQL as in my answe,r this implies there's more at hand, @MarkFoley . I suspect Martin Smith is right in the comment under your question *"Any Triggers?*"

Comment: Ah! I missed Martin Smith's comment. Of course! I checked the insert trigger and yes, it was catenating a varchar with the numeric rate to log to a change record. I changed that to catenating the varchar value with convert(varchar,rate), and the insert worked! Thanks a for the help!

Comment: BTW - this is my first stackoverflow post and I don't see how to mark an answer as accepted or a question as solved. I find nothing to 'click'

Comment: @MarkFoley Sorry for late response, you can upvote helpful answers (no matter how many) also you can mark it as answer below the upvote/downvote button

Comment: Sorry, newbie. I want to up-vote and mark as answered Martin Smith's Jan 3 comment, but under 'Answers' I see only Larnu's and your (RezaRahmati) comment, not Martin's.

Comment: @MarkFoleyI don't see his answer either, what I see related to Martin is his comment under your question